# Changing the value of capacitor

Tags: capacitor, analog, emc

What is the effects of replacing signed capacitors with 4uF ones related to Emi Filter performance (Electromagnetic compatibility issues).
We observed that the time with 4uF ones keeps longer (power to circuit) when power-off then 1uF ones but not sure how the emi performance will change.
(By the way, are they by pass capacitors?) Thanks.

[image: Filter Design]Hi,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emi filter is an AC device. Operating this with AC voltage, no matter how big the capacitor is, "keep power longer to circuit" is an absurd statement, unless you use it with DC supply. But then, in DC application the inductance in the filter will be totally useless.

Filters are designed to attenuate particular band or bands of interference from getting into (or out from) the circuit of interest, for instance a switching mode power supply.

To achieve that goal firstly the noise spectrum of the SMPS is analyzed using a spectrum analyzer. Then the filter components (the henries and  farads) will be chosen to achieve the best attenuation for the noise frequencies detected by the analyzer. Inductors will be sized to handle the required load current and capacitors are sized for the desired operating voltage.

Having said this, you must understand the components inside a filter are application specific and should not be meddled.

Comment: Thanks for the response. " DC application the inductance in the filter will be totally useless." It's true inductance does not affect steady-state DC. But any attempt to change that DC current level will be opposed by any inductance in the circuit. Can you evaluate larger capacitor replacing, will it be appropriate filtering for 461f mil standart?

Comment: "Any attempt to change that DC current level" is always best dealt with larger capacitor rather than inductor because the former helps to reduce power supply impedance but the latter do exactly opposite. But inductor can be used in DC supply sourced from  everywhere else except batteries to filter out any AC signal riding on DC.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you are thinking that bigger is better.Remember that real caps have a self resonant frequency that can be represented by the cap and an inductor in series .The inductance is the total of the leads and the PCB traces.When you put your big 4 microfarad in place of the 1 microfarad the parasitic inductance wont change much .This Quadrupling of C whilst leaving L will halve the self resonant frequency of the system.Your risk here is that your EMC plot will be worse at the high end .Even if you are better at the low end it could still mean a FAIL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Requirement here is to comply to MIL-STD-461. But it seems we are reducing fcutoff and will be less tolerated to high frequency noises am i right ? Does this changes request retest 461f or not? One more question: What about using  8uF (for CF6) and 1uF ( for CF1, as it is) Does it better then 4uF/4uF condition as 1uF can still filter high frequencies and no filter performence degration and test will not be needed ?

Answer (score 2):

A capacitor has all kinds of internal effects. Such as a series resistance and a virtual inductance, those even exists on the plates inside, 4μF has more plate area, i.e. more inductance and most likely more resistance, unless you go for a much larger package.

In fact, it sounds like you just plonked the EMI filter in there. That may work well in many cases, but without the proper maths and knowledge of the kinds of interference you are causing and you are susceptible to, the entire filter may have been wrong for you anyway. Or if not wrong close to useless. We cannot say. Maybe accidentally a 4μF capacitor would have fixed it. Or it may also have made it ten times worse.

We can't say, because we don't know your device.

If you have had the EMI filter in a device that was tested by a reputable testing house and it passed, then replacing the caps with 4μF will potentially cause one or more frequency bands that can pass enough energy through it that will then trigger a test failure.

The safest thing to do (if you think the filter is okay *now*), if you want more capacitance in your system is to not replace anything, but just add a 10μF cap on the board in the product somewhere. Preferably close to what uses the current. And then just leave the whole filter as is.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can not add a 10uF cap as pcb design ended and will need to analyze new emi performance. Requirement here was/is to comply to MIL-STD-461 and the product (shared emi filter circuit) passed tests. "but without the proper maths and knowledge of the kinds of interference you are causing and you are susceptible to" how can i know what frequencies should i filter? I use 28v dc power source and need to comply 461f. I tested and saw this problem 4/4 will be okey for more capacitance but not sure emi test should be reperform or not.